# Basic C++ problem - Using variable within the class

Tags: c++

I have problem with C++ class. Is there have any way to reuse variable in the same class in the header file?

I have try

```
PubSubClient mqttClient(this->secureClient);
PubSubClient mqttClient(mqtt.secureClient);
```

but fail. Why?

```
#ifndef __MQTT_H_
#define __MQTT_H_

#include "Arduino.h"
#include "WiFi.h"
#include "WiFiClientSecure.h"
#include "PubSubClient.h"

class MQTT
{
public:

bool initWiFi();
String macAddress6btye(void);
void callback(char *topic, byte *payload, unsigned int length);
bool mqttConnect();
bool mqttPublish(const String &endPoint, const String &payload);
int getStrength(uint8_t points);

private:
    WiFiClientSecure secureClient;
    PubSubClient mqttClient(this->secureClient);
};

#endif
```

Comment: I think you might need to invest in [some good C++ books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list/388282#388282).

Comment: CPP is C preprocessor. It does not have classes. What you have mentioned is C++.

Comment: On another (but unrelated) note, your function named `callback` worries me. Callback functions need special handling if done as non-static member functions. You might want to study more about pointers to member functions and the difference between pointers to non-member functions.

Comment: `__MQTT_H_` is a reserved name. You shouldn't be using it in your own code. All identifiers that contain two consecutive underscores (`__`) or start with underscore followed by a capital letter are reserved for the implementation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The declaration

```
PubSubClient mqttClient(this->secureClient);
```

is treated as a *function* declaration. An invalid one.

If you want to *initialize* the member variable (using other member variables), you need to do it with a *constructor initializer list*:

```
class MQTT
{
public:
    MQTT()
        : secureClient(),
          mqttClient(secureClient)  // Initialization here
    {
        // Empty function body
    }

    // ...

    WiFiClientSecure secureClient;
    PubSubClient mqttClient;  // No initialization here
};
```

Comment: I found a solution should be working      ```MQTT(WiFiClientSecure secureClient)
    {
        PubSubClient mqttClient(secureClient);
    }; ``` The relation between the variable, constructor and the class is quite a complicated one. Still not very understand it. @Some Programmer dude, Thank for the tips. It open a new area for me.

Comment: @Samuel That code you show defines a *local* variable with the name `mqttClient` inside the constructor body. It's a totally separate variable from the member variable of the same name. Why don't you just copy-paste the code I've shown in my answer (now updated to initialize both member variables)?